# How to dynamically change variable in php

Tags: php

I have a token for a specific ID number which is 494

```
$url = api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/494/products?start=0&api_token=7ecb71622dadd2faae2732bfe73b09381150c967;
```

I want to change the number 494 to any number.

I've made an illogical code to begin with.

Any guide on how to do this?

```
$url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/";
$id = 494;
$api = "/products?start=0&api_token=7ecb71622dadd2faae2732bfe73b09381150c967";

$response = file_get_contents($url+$id+$api);
echo $response;

$object = json_decode($response, true);
```

I got the errorL

> Warning: file_get_contents(494): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory

Comment: Could you clarify what problem you want to solve? Because it just sounds like you want to redeclare variables: $id = 123;

Comment: `+` isn't used for concatenation in PHP.

Comment: @Thomas yeah, I wanted to be able to change the $id dynamically and call the complete token the same as the first $url above

Comment: @Devon yeah I figured too. Do you know anyway to call the $url, $id, and $api in file_get_contents?

Comment: use "." instead of "+" for concatenating...and use die() to print your url to check whether its in correct formate...

Comment: @AntheaMarie the PHP manual is useful: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: @RohitS Thanks mate. Your advice helped :)

Comment: @Devon Thank you! Will look more through it

Comment: @happy to help :D

Answer (score 2):

You are using '+' operator to concatenate. Which sums two variable.
You need to use concatenation operator ('.') not '+'

```
$url = $url.$id.$api;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `.` is used for string concatenation. Also you can use the `.=` to append a string to a string variable. Example:

```
$str = "Hello";
$str2 = $str . "Anthea"; // $str2 = "Hello Anthea"
```

Or

```
$str = "Hello";
$str .= "Anthea"; // $str = "Hello Anthea"
```